# My DataGridView blinks when refreshing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

If I refresh some data in my datagridview, I **lose my focus on selected cells** and **random text blinks**.

Why does this happen? In other apps I don't see this problem, so I can fix this, but how?

I refresh data by this code:

```
SBind.DataSource = DTable; // SBind is binded my grid.DataSource = SBind
SBind.ResetBindings(false);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
SBind.SuspendLayout();
SBind.DataSource = DTable;
SBind.ResetBindings(false);
SBind.ResumeLayout(true);
```

You can also try enabling the `DoubleBuffered` of your grid like this:

```
typeof(Control).GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
               .SetValue(SBind, true, null);
```

Comment: @Greag.Deay just save some identity (to identify the selected row) and  then after refreshing the grid, find that row and mark it as selected. Anyway, I'm not sure why you need to refresh the grid this way.

Answer (score 0):

This could help too:

```
dataGridView1.DoubleBuffered(true);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t7htc9c(v=vs.110).aspx